# In ChromaDB, when querying, can I see how many items match the "filter"?

Tags: langchain, vector-database, chromadb

I'm using Chroma as my vector database in LangChain.
I query using filters, using LangChain's wrapper around the collection.query() function in Chroma.

vectordb.similarity_search_with_score(query_document, k=n_results, filter = {...})

I want to find not only the items that are most similar, but also the number of items that went through the filter.

Looking at the Chroma docs, I don't see how that's done.
Can anyone help?

I tried looking through the docs, but didn't find the answer there.